# Why are grid lines not showing in my plot?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, visualization

I'm trying to plot distribution plot using seaborn but not getting the gridlines in the plot it is plain.

```
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

sns.distplot(df_0['temp'], bins=20)
```

Image for reference:

[image]

Comment: There are no gridlines by default. Did you follow any of the seaborn examples in the documentation? Did you write any code line to turn the grid on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sns.distplot(df_0['temp'], bins=20).grid()`

seaborn.distplot returns the underlying Matplotlib axes object, so you can further manipulate it. For example:

```
ax = sns.distplot(df_0['temp'], bins=20)
ax.grid()
ax.axvline(10)
```

Also, as shown in seaborn documentation, you can get grid lines along with other asesthetics by setting the seaborn style:

```
seaborn.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.distplot(df_0['temp'], bins=20)
```

Comment: Histogram vertical lines are also not showing for the graph it is showing in dissolved. I want to get vertical white lines also for separation between bars

Comment: Add `hist_kws={'edgecolor': 'white'}` to your displot call. If my answer solves the problem, please upvote it and mark it as correct, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are no grid-lines by default.
Added `hist_kws={'edgecolor': 'white'}` to my distplot call.